# emacs lisp, how to get buffer major mode?

Tags: emacs, elisp, major-mode

I have tried to search Google and look in the manual, but still cannot find how to get major mode of a buffer object.  Can you help me with an example or a reference.  Thanks

only solution I could find was to query major-mode after changing the buffer and then changing back to original buffer. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Is there a problem with that?

```
(defun buffer-mode (buffer-or-string)
  "Returns the major mode associated with a buffer."
  (with-current-buffer buffer-or-string
     major-mode))
```

`with-current-buffer` will restore your buffer when it returns.

Comment: You could also do this with `(with-current-buffer buffer-or-string major-mode)` instead of `save-excursion`.

Comment: @haxney: Using `(save-excursion (set-buffer ..) ...)` is indeed deprecated in favor of `(with-current-buffer ...)`.  The byte-compiler of Emacs-24 warns about such uses.

Comment: @stefan: Where might an emacs noob see such deprecations?

Comment: As noted, the byte-compiler warns about it: just byte-compile your files, it will give you useful advice.

Comment: It works, but I'm curious if emacs can handle this straightforward? Why should we change the target buffer shortly to current, apply function, and change it back? Why isn't there a function that takes a buffer and return its major-mode directly? Is it for some historical convention? Or there are deeper facts in emacs that prevent us doing that?

Answer (score 41):

For current buffer:

```
(message "%s" major-mode)
```

Answer (score 37):

A simple way to do this is to use the `buffer-local-value` function since `major-mode` is a buffer-local variable:

```
(buffer-local-value 'major-mode (get-buffer "*scratch*"))
```

Comment: This actually answers the original asker's question. which is how to do this without switching buffers.

Answer (score 8):

Just extending from previous answers - call with no arguments to get the current buffer's mode:

```
(defun buffer-mode (&optional buffer-or-name)
  "Returns the major mode associated with a buffer.
If buffer-or-name is nil return current buffer's mode."
  (buffer-local-value 'major-mode
   (if buffer-or-name (get-buffer buffer-or-name) (current-buffer))))
```

E.g. in *scratch* buffer:

```
(buffer-mode) => 'lisp-interaction-mode

(buffer-mode "tasks.org") => 'org-mode
```

Comment: Thanks for offering a comprehensive solution!

Answer (score 0):

Well, describe-mode takes an optional buffer argument, but that displays the help... and I'm not exactly sure what it returns...

But that's the best I could find in a brief search... sorry...

Answer (score 0):

Simply evaluate this:

```
(print major-mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way, apart from directly readind the *`major-mode`* variable would be by directly readind the *`mode-name`* variable.