# Detect current major mode in Emacs (from Lisp)?

Tags: emacs, elisp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [emacs lisp, how to get buffer major mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238418/emacs-lisp-how-to-get-buffer-major-mode)

Is there a way for Emacs Lisp code to determine the current major mode?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can look at the value of the variable `major-mode`.

Comment: +1.  Thanks.  I'll mark this as the accepted answer sometime when SO will let me accept it.

Comment: For those other travelers who may come here like I did on day 3 of using emacs to do so you can either use C-h v <variable to describe> or the command describe-variable to view the value of the var.